# D3 choropleth map with legend

Tags: javascript, d3.js, maps, range, legend

I have a choropleth map of the united states showing total population. I would like to add a legend to the map showing the quantile range values.I’ve seen other similar questions about this topic but can’t seem to get it to work for my specific case. I know I need to include the color range or color domain but just not sure if this is the correct way. As of right now just one feature shows up in the legend, could it be that all the legend features are stacked on top of each other. How can I know for sure and how can I fix this.

```
//Define default colorbrewer scheme
var colorSchemeSelect = "Greens";
var colorScheme = colorbrewer[colorSchemeSelect]; 

//define default number of quantiles
var quantiles = 5;

//Define quantile scale to sort data values into buckets of color
var color = d3.scale.quantile()
   .range(colorScheme[quantiles]);

d3.csv(data, function (data) {
    color.domain([
         d3.min(data, function (d) {
           return d.value;
         }),
         d3.max(data, function (d
           return d.value
         }) 
    ]);

//legend                            
var legend = svg.selectAll('rect')
    .data(color.domain().reverse())
    .enter()
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x", width - 780)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .style("fill", color);
```

Comment: Something like [this](http://bl.ocks.org/KoGor/5685876)? You would just need to set the range of output colors to be quantiles (i.e. 5 colors).

Comment: Yes I would like it to be similar to that example. I don’t want to have a variable with hard coded values for the legend like the example uses though. I want it to use the color.domain and colorScheme variable to populate the legend values.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The legend code that you're using would work perfectly well if you had an *ordinal scale*, where the domain is made up of discrete values that correlate to the range of colours on a one-to-one basis.  But you're using a *quantile scale*, and so need a different approach.

For a [d3 quantile scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantile), the domain is the list of all possible input values, and the range is a list of discrete output values.  The domain list is sorted in ascending order and then divided into equal-sized groups, which are assigned to each output value from the range.  The number of groups is determined by the number of output values.

With that in mind, in order to get one legend entry for each colour, you're going to need to use your colour scale's *range*, not the domain, as the data for your legend.  Then you can use the [`quantileScale.invertExtent()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantile_invertExtent) method to find the minimum and maximum input values that are getting drawn with that colour.

Sample code, making each legend entry a `<g>` containing both the coloured rectangle and a text label showing the corresponding values.

```
var legend = svg.selectAll('g.legendEntry')
    .data(color.range().reverse())
    .enter()
    .append('g').attr('class', 'legendEntry');

legend
    .append('rect')
    .attr("x", width - 780)
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
   .attr("width", 10)
   .attr("height", 10)
   .style("stroke", "black")
   .style("stroke-width", 1)
   .style("fill", function(d){return d;}); 
       //the data objects are the fill colors

legend
    .append('text')
    .attr("x", width - 765) //leave 5 pixel space after the <rect>
    .attr("y", function(d, i) {
       return i * 20;
    })
    .attr("dy", "0.8em") //place text one line *below* the x,y point
    .text(function(d,i) {
        var extent = color.invertExtent(d);
        //extent will be a two-element array, format it however you want:
        var format = d3.format("0.2f");
        return format(+extent[0]) + " - " + format(+extent[1]);
    });
```

Comment: By the way, looking at the rest of your code, it looks like what you really want to use is a [d3 *quantize* scale](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Quantitative-Scales#wiki-quantize) (not *quantile*), for which the domain is a `[min,max]` range and the scale divides that into groups representing equal-sized extent of the domain variable (rather than equal number of observations).  The legend code above works the same for either type of scale, since in both cases the number of groups is determined by the range array, and the corresponding domain values can be accessed using `invertExtent`.

Comment: Thank you so much for your thoughtful answer! I wish I could up vote your answer but I don't have enough reputations for that yet.  I am just having problems with the .invertExtent() method from the sample code. It is giving me an error in the console and is not displaying  the text associated with the legend.

Comment: Are you using the latest version of d3?  It [looks like the `invertExtent` method was only added for quantize and threshold scales in version 3.2](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/v3.2.0).  With the latest version:  [here's a live version with a quantize scale](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jM5H9); and [here it is with a quantile scale](http://fiddle.jshell.net/jM5H9/1/).  I had to make a couple tidy-up changes (to the formatting function and the alignment of the text, I'll update the sample code above), but neither of those problems were causing errors.

Comment: (The `invertExtent` method was added for [quantile scales in 3.2.4](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/releases/tag/v3.2.4), latest version from [d3js.org](http://d3js.org/) is 3.4.2.)

Comment: I wasn't using the latest version so that solved my problem! Thank you! Have you heard of the latest version of D3 causing problems with map projection?